# Angualr4 UI slows down with large array of objects

Tags: angular

[image: This is the table i'm using to represent all the items for a supply]

Shown above is the table used to show the array of objects. Item count usuall exceeds 50~60. At which point elements in the interface like transition animations and click event take time.

I've noticed however if I filtered the items which returns 1 or 2 items the UI speeds up again.

What's the practical approach to normalize the response time of my UI + make sure all items are visible to the user.

My backend is Firebase using AngularFire.

Comment: It should not be a problem when you bind data within the range of 1-1000

Answer (score 1):

50 - 60 objects should not normally create performance problems in Angular, but it's hard to say what the issue is without knowing more about your application.

If updating the table is slow, though, you should check that you have specified `trackBy` when you use `*ngFor`. See the [Angular documentation for *ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf). It will speed up the updating of larger tables.